# ERROR: The Python zlib extension was not compiled. Missing the zlib?

Tags: bash, macos, python-2.7, homebrew, pyenv

I'm trying to install  **Python 2.7.7** using  **Homebrew AND pyenv** on my Mac (MacBook Air, OSX 12.5 Monterrey, 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5) but keep getting this “Missing zlib” error.

**Just for reference, I have done the following:**

1. When I Installed pyenv, I ran command `nano ~/.bashrc` (I'm using bash shell) - and pasted and saved on **/.bashrc** ---> `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`
2. then I ran `pyenv install 2.7.7` (didn't work and found online step 3.)
3. `CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include" pyenv install -v 2.7.7` (Again, same error and did step 4.)
4. ran `brew reinstall zlib` and overrode on "/.bashrc" `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/bzip2/include"
```

-------------Start of Error ----------------

```
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/python2
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin; ln -s python2.7 python2)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/python2-config
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin; ln -s python2.7-config python2-config)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/python-config
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin; ln -s python2-config python-config)
test -d /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig || /usr/bin/install -c -d -m 755 /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig/python2.pc
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python-2.7.pc python2.pc)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python2.pc python.pc)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1/python2.1
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.7.1 python2.1)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1/python.1
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.1 python.1)
ERROR: The Python zlib extension was not compiled. Missing the zlib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.5 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/__/1_b0871s7fl7fpwydg4ycjj80000gn/T/python-build.20220729111901.75727
Results logged to /var/folders/__/1_b0871s7fl7fpwydg4ycjj80000gn/T/python-build.20220729111901.75727.log

Last 10 log lines:
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin; ln -s python2-config python-config)
test -d /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig || /usr/bin/install -c -d -m 755 /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig/python2.pc
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python-2.7.pc python2.pc)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python2.pc python.pc)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1/python2.1
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.7.1 python2.1)
rm -f /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1/python.1
(cd /Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.1 python.1)
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ 
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ 
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ 
Victors-MacBook-Air:~ victor$ software update
-bash: software: command not found
```

------------- End of Error -----------------

**Any idea?.... Please let me know... I'd highly appreciate it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a similar configuration, 2018 MBA on Monterey, I was having the same problem as you with `pyenv` install 2.7.6

I was able to go past the missing `zlib` issue with the following additions to the shell's profile:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

As a side note, the installation still didn't go through due to a different issue:
[image]

That OpenSSL issue has to do with OpenSSL 1.0 being EOL, [more info here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#2-your-openssl-version-is-incompatible-with-the-python-version-youre-trying-to-install).

At the end I just went with 2.7.14 which is OpenSSL 2.0 compatible and good enough for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

> command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

This is indicating you need to use the Settings to update the command line tools.

```
$ software update
-bash: software: command not found
```

There is no command line called "software". Instead open system preferences. Then click on this:
[image: software update]

Install any updates requested.